# Bulk Import of Files to SFDC

Tags: files

In the *distant past* I have migrated thousands of files to Salesforce as 'Attachments'.

I am currently on a project where I need to migrate thousands of files to Salesforce as 'Files' - this will be an unfamiliar task for me. As I understand it the process is similar (ie. upload via Apex Data Loader using a suitably populated csv). However my searching for the correct procedure has produced no clear instructions (not clear to me anyway).

For example:

1 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232998&type=1

2 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_content.htm&type=5

3 https://www.simplysfdc.com/2018/02/salesforce-mass-upload-files-to-files.html

Nos. 2 and 3 appear very similar (and if I was more SFDC savvy perhaps they would turn out to be the same), but the first one (Trailblazer) is different in that it advises the creation of **two** csv files and what appears to be a different process.

Am I on the right track here? Maybe someone who has done this before can point me to 'best practice'  instructions?

Comment: Do you want to move the same attachment you have in your system as files?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a File and associating an uploaded File with a particular record is actually a 2-step process. In summary, you will need to perform:

1. Load the file data into the [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) object
2. You then export the [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) records and by using the success file generated on the first step, get the corresponding `ContentDocumentId` for those files. Then you create a new CSV file with the `ContentDocumentId` and associate those to the respective records in Salesforce and insert data in the [`ContentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm%20object) object

The [first link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232998&type=1) in your question details these steps. I haven't done too many of File uploads, but whenever I have been in that situation, I have followed these steps.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead. Do you have chance to update link?

Comment: The dead link was from the question itself, and I don't have any recollection what was that.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with bulk file uploads can indeed be a challenging task, but there are efficient solutions available. Let me guide you through a specialized solution that might streamline the process for you.

You can try the Mass File Upload Appexchnage app, which will provide you with a smooth and easy solution. You won't have to worry about complicated CSV file uploads; the app allows you to upload large numbers of files, attachments, library files, and simple CSV files that simply require the file name and record ID to be uploaded from your system to Salesforce. This is a very easy and seamless process that allows you to upload your bulk files/attachments to your standard or custom Salesforce object with just a few clicks with a simple two-column CSV file. No complicated CSV creation or data load struggles are required.

User-Friendly Interface: The Mass File Upload app provides a smooth and intuitive user experience, eliminating the complexities associated with traditional data loading methods.

**Bulk File Upload:** This application saves you the trouble of creating complex CSV files by allowing you to upload large numbers of files straight from your system to Salesforce. You can choose individual records based on your needs and upload files in bulk using its ListView, SOQL, and Recoed search features.

**Simple CSV Format:** Instead of dealing with complex CSV structures, the app simplifies the process by requiring only two columns in your CSV file: Record ID and File Name.

Mass File Upload AppExhange - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=82cf236b-1ee8-4ea7-aebf-fd0c89fb93bd

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Upload AppExchange App.

Thanks,
Nikita